# The print() method is not working in my Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, methods, printing

Somehow the print() method is not recognized anymore, I even tried reinstalling Xcode but no luck!

[image: Showing the error]

Comment: You need to put it inside something that gets executed, like a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `print` statement outside the body of function is not allowed . You can use print statement either  inside the `viewDidLoad` function or you can make your custom function and then use it.

You can use it inside your function Like this.

```
func CustomFunction()  {
    
    print("Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `print("Hello")` into your `viewDidLoad()` method. Place it between the curly braces following your `viewDidLoad()` method. As Phillip said, it must be written inside something that is executed, such as this function.

Your code should then look something like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Write your code here...
        print("Hello")
    }
```